# RecursionError composing lambdas

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, lambda

I am trying to write a function that composes any number of lambda functions.

I have two simple lambda functions.

```
f = lambda x: x + 1
g = lambda x: x**2
```

My attempt at a composing function is this:

```
def compose(*functions):
    composed = lambda x: x  # Function that returns input
    for function in reversed(functions):
        composed = lambda x: function(composed(x))
    return composed
```

My thinking was to loop through the variable number of functions, each time making the `composed` function include a new function inside it.

Then I could make a function that is a composition of `f` and `g`

```
c = compose(f, g)
```

So calling `c(5)` should return `f(g(5))`, which is 26. But instead, I get

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I thought introducing an intermediate variable might fix the problem.

```
def compose(*functions):
    composed = lambda x: x  # Function that returns input
    for function in reversed(functions):
        intermediate = lambda x: function(composed(x))
        composed = intermediate
    return composed
```

But the same error is raised.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think your approach will suffer from *late closure binding*, as `function` in lambda will only take the last value of function at the end of the iteration. Secondly, `composed` will only call itself recursively in the end also due to the first reason; `composed` - the lambda - calls the last value of `composed` - itself!

One possible fix is to bind `composed` and `function` to the `lambda` at each iteration:

```
def compose(*functions):
    composed = lambda x: x
    for function in reversed(functions):
        composed = lambda x, function=function, composed=composed: function(composed(x))
    return composed

print(compose(f, g)(5))
# 26
```

But your overall problem looks like a good use case for [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

def compose(*functions):
    def inner(v):
        return reduce(lambda x, y: y(x),  reversed(functions), v)
    return inner

print(compose(f, g)(5))
# 26
```

Comment: Good solution, but can you spot the bug in the OP's attempt?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Having a look at it

Comment: yeah, just figured out it was due to late-binding.